# how can I monitor a folder for new files or folders

Tags: php

Using PHP, I am trying to create a monitoring or watch script that will let me know that a new file or folder has been created. I am not sure if it is possible in PHP or do I have to use any other program to monitor the folder.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can check a folder's ctime. Depending on the platform, this will have varying degrees of success. If you're on Windows, there are a lot of quirks related to the filesystem and unicode. You'll have to set up a cron or scheduled task to run your script periodically, though, it won't run itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can create a cronjob or an infinite loop with a sleep period, that will initially map the folder, then listen for changes.